# Recommended App Insights application type for bot?

Tags: botframework, azure-application-insights

When registering a new bot with the [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new) there is an option for App Insights intrumentation key.

Does it matter what Application Type I choose for the App Insights instance?
I'm guessing it would be between "General" or "ASP.NET web application".

Comment: the application types generally just affect which overview experiences/etc you have.  either will work, but the "asp.net web" experience is more fleshed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bot is a web application, webApi.
I'm using ASP.NET Web Application without problems.